# GeoIP / IP name & location resolution in unicorn logs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, unicorn

I'm at a point in my web application where it is useful to see ip addresses resolved down to location (for example with MaxMind) and DNS name via reverse lookup of the IPs.  I'm running unicorn on Heroku and other servers.  Is there a prebuilt method of doing this or do I need to write some kind of a filter to pass my logs through in order to provide this additional information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like http://www.rubygeocoder.com/ to determine the location of the user based of their IP address and then use that within your application. An exact example of what it sounds like you're trying to do is on their homepage

```
request.ip  # =>    "81.137.210.82"
request.location.city   # =>    "Erith"
request.location.country    # =>    "United Kingdom"
```